# Create link in selectize's dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

Good day,

I am using the plugin [selectize](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) for my projects select elements, it looks good and simple but I just want to ask if how do I make the option list become links to other pages?

heres my simple html code

```
<div class="control-group">
                <label for="sreport-select">Search:</label>
                <select id="report-select" class="demo-default" placeholder="Select Report">
                    <option value="">Select Report</option>
                    <option value="4"><a href="home">Profit and Loss</a></option>
                    <option value="1"><a href="link">Balance Sheet</a></option>
                    <option value="2"><a href="test">Expenses</a></option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

and my js

```
<script>
  $('#report-select').selectize({
  create: false,
  sortField: {
  field: 'text',
  direction: 'asc'
 }
</script>
```

I did tried adding some  on option list but nothing is happening. Any information or suggestion would really be appreciated! Thanks and have a Good day!

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
<label for="sreport-select">Search:</label>
<select id="report-select" class="demo-default" placeholder="Select Report">
    <option value="">Select Report</option>
    <option value="home">Profit and Loss</option>
    <option value="link">Balance Sheet</option>
    <option value="test">Expenses</option>
</select>
```

And add this to your javascript:

```
$('#report-select').change(function(){
    if ( $(this).val() !== '' ) {
        window.open($(this).val(), '_self');
    }
});
```

This simulates a link click in javascript, so you won't actually need links in your select group.